# c# finding indexof and remove character atsign

Tags: c#

there is a String which contains some @ characters, i want to find " @ " in my string and remove them, but it also finds and removes these ones: "@"

```
int atsignPlace = str.IndexOf(" @ ");
while (atsignPlace >= 0)
{
    str = str.Remove(atsignPlace,3);
    atsignPlace = str.IndexOf(" @ ");
}
```

i tried this code, but it removes nothing, so it always finds first '@' ,which makes it an infinite loop.

```
int atsignPlace = str.IndexOf(" @");
while (atsignPlace >= 0)
{
    if( atsignPlace+1 < str.Length && str[atsignPlace+1] == ' ' )
        str = str.Remove(atsignPlace,3);
    atsignPlace = str.IndexOf(" @ ");
 }
```

Replace method also doesn't work correct.

```
str = str.Replace(" @ ", String.Empty);
```

maybe there is a problem with '@' character.

the input string is a sql query, i am trying to remove some parameters from it.

[ i have used try-catch for exceptions ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine. Short but complete program to demonstrate:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main() 
    {
        string before = "xyz @ abc@123";
        string after = CustomRemove(before);
        Console.WriteLine(after); // Prints xyzabc@123
    }

    static string CustomRemove(string text)
    {
        int atSignIndex = text.IndexOf(" @ ");
        while (atSignIndex >= 0)
        {
            text = text.Remove(atSignIndex, 3);
            atSignIndex = text.IndexOf(" @ ");
        }
        return text;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Of course, `Replace` works fine too:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main() 
    {
        string before = "xyz @ abc@123";
        string after = before.Replace(" @ ", "");
        Console.WriteLine(after); // Prints xyzabc@123
    }
}
```

If you're still seeing a problem with *either* of these, then the issue is in how you're using this code, not in the code itself.

One guess: you might have non-printed characters within the " @ " which is preventing them from being removed. But you haven't really given us enough information to say. A short but complete program *demonstrating* it not working would help...

Comment: this code is some how just a copy of my code, i mentioned in question that it doesn't work:(

Comment: @rene: That's why I started the answer with **Your** code works fine. It's a demonstration of it working. You claim it's not working - I'm demonstrating that it does. Either you're not reading your diagnostics correctly, or the bug is how you're *using* your code, or you haven't described your problem accurately.

Comment: the input string is a sql query, i am trying to remove some parameters from it. for example the string below is given: `"insert into [item] (x_id,  y_id ) values ( @x_id,  @y_id)";`

Comment: @rene: Well that doesn't contain " @ " does it? So there's nothing to remove... If you'd said that in the first place, we'd have been able to explain the flaw in your approach without going through your non-working code. Sounds like you probably just want a regex. What result do you really want though? Just completely removing the parameter won't leave valid SQL...

Comment: i am trying to remove some of the parameters, for example x_id. when i replace '@x_id' with a space or String.Empty, it removes 'x_id' but remains its '@' character! too complicated:(

Comment: @rene: No, it really won't. It would help if you could give *full* examples of these non-working situations...

Comment: u mean if i delete x_id and @x_id from the insert command, it wont gives me a valid command?

Comment: @rene: Indeed - in what way would `"insert into [item (, y_id ) values (, @y_id)"` be valid SQL?

Comment: i handled it, no problem. the real problem is removing the atsing char, as i said above, i just wanted to simply explain the intend of program. have u tested the code in Q ?

Comment: @rene: Yes - but in *complete* programs, as shown in my answers. (Not the middle snippet in the question, which is broken, but the first and second.) We can't tell what the "real problem" is while you keep switching things around. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: i think i should change whole solution for editing the given query,you are right

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple:

```
string result = input.Replace(" @ ", String.Empty);
```

MSDN: [String.Replace Method (String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx)

Comment: The question is hard to understand, but the OP only wants to remove ` @ ` (surrounded by a space), not every `@`.

Comment: No, read the first line of their post: `i want to find " @ " in my string and remove them, but it also finds and removes these ones: "@"`

Comment: @SimpleCoder : thanks, so why just not replace one substring by String.Empty? Event simpler.

Comment: what's wrong with just *var newstring = input.Replace(" @ ", string.Empty)?*

Comment: this code does not work correctly, i don't know why but just try it.

Comment: @rene: We've tried it, it works. We've tried your code, it works. The problem is in what you're *doing* with the code, and you haven't shown us that.

Answer (score 0):

I would use regex to make sure that you get any number of whitespaces:

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"\s+@\s+", m => string.Empty);
```

Comment: Don't assume that the OP wants to remove ` @ ` no matter how many spaces surround it - they never specified that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
string LclString = "@12 @ 123@123 @ @";
LclString = LclString.Replace(" @ ", "  ");
```

Yields this:
@12  123@123  @